# Stop rotation and moving

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

How stop the rotation and moving of the body?

I do this:

```
            mBody.setAngularDamping(100);
            mBody.setLinearDamping(100);
```

but it does not stop the body completely, and

```
            mBody.setActive(false);
```

it not freeze body fully.

Comment: Sherman, you can't just post a question and then ignore it. You need to upvote and accept answers, otherwise people will stop answering your questions completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to stop:

```
body->setLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0,0));
body->setAngularVelocity(0);
```

If you want your body to become immovable - make it static:

```
body->setType(b2_staticBody);
```

Comment: Just to clarify this a little bit, b2Vec2 is Vector2 in AndEngine.